# JavaScript nav menu doesn't close when item, other than the first, is clicked

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle, nav

So I've got this JS mobile nav menu. When the menu button is clicked the menu opens, and can then be closed by pressing the menu button again. I also want the menu to close when one of the nav items is clicked. With the code below, I managed to make the menu close when the first item is clicked but for reasons unknown to myself it doesn't work for the other three nav items. Has it maybe got something to do with the way I'm selecting the `nav-item` class? Also, my Javascript knowledge is very limited so there might be something obvious I'm missing.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="main-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <div class="sidebar is-hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav-item page-scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item page-scroll" href="#framing">FRAMING</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item page-scroll" href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-item page-scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**JS**

```
const button = document.querySelector('.nav-menu')
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
const item = document.querySelector('.nav-item')

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-hidden')
});

item.addEventListener('click', function () {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-hidden')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `document.querySelector` returns first found element. If you want to add event listener to more than one element, you should use `document.querySelectorAll` method instead. You will receive a list of elements. You want to add event listener to each of them.

Comment: Hi, changing it from `document.querySelector` to `window.querySelectorAll` made it so none of the items closed the menu. I also tried `document.querySelectorAll` and it did the same.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll returns a list of elements. If you want to apply eventListener to each of the elements you need to iterate through the list. There are many ways to do that. E.g. use a simple for loop 
`const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')` `for(let i=0; i<navItems.length; i++){}` or forEach method: `navItems.forEach(function(navItem) {})`

Comment: If you still have problems here is the solution: `navItems.forEach(
    function (navItem) {
        navItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
            sidebar.classList.toggle('is-hidden')
        })
    }
);`

Comment: Just tried this and was almost certain it would work, because it looks like it should, but it didn't... Could this be due to other code being incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: Ok so just checked the console and noticed that it says `TypeError: navItems.forEach is not a function`. What does this mean?

Comment: Make sure you change this: `const item = document.querySelector('.nav-item')` to `const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')`

Comment: Yup!! That's it! Cheers for the help mate! Apologies for my misunderstandings!